# If the electoral votes were not certified on January 6, who would be president?

Tags: united-states, congress

On January 6, 2021, thousands of Trump supporters breached the US capitol building demanding that Mike Pence refuse to certify the election and overturn it in his favor. Despite massive civil unrest, the electoral votes were certified with Biden winning by the margin Trump won by in 2016, 306-232.

Hypothetically, who would have became President if the electoral votes were NOT certified? Would Nancy Pelosi have become the President given she was the speaker, and the 3rd in line of succession is the Speaker?

Comment: What research have you done into this question?

Comment: No, the plan was to count "uncontested States" only.  After that was done, magically Trump would have won.  There was never a plan to move down the chain of succession.  see https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/81235/21531 :  "Scenario #1" #2 is what you need to look at -it's a long answer.

Comment: @NumberFile You are thinking of the line of succession to president.  The speaker of the house would be #2 after the VP, in Trump's case Pense.  The  issue on Jan 6th wasn't  who would replace trump as if he had died.  The issue was who won the Nov 2020 election.   The machinations were all about ensuring that would be President Trump although the election ballot determined otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

> **Question:**
>
> Hypothetically, who would have became President if the electoral votes were NOT certified? Would Nancy Pelosi have become the President given she was the speaker, and the 3rd in line of succession is the Speaker?

**Short Answer:**

The objective of President Trump's seven-part plan to overturn the election was to create a Constitutional crisis. Using the Republican Majority in the Supreme Court to throw the decision into various state legislatures where Republicans held the majority.  They were to recognize fake electors, which would then be used to overturn the real election.  The intermediate goal of the capital riot was to delay the certification of the vote and give the other parts of the plan time to work.  The ultimate goal was for President Trump to remain in office despite having lost the 2020 election.

**Answer:**

Hypothetically the breaching of the capital was only the last phase of a seven-part plan to keep President Trump in power and deny the results of the 2020 election.  President Trump's advisor Peter Navarro detailed the plan in his 2021 book.  He called it The **[Greenbay Sweep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_Bay_Sweep_(politics))** after a famous American football play which was used successfully so often that all the people watching new it was coming but the opponents still couldn't stop it.  **[Peter Navarro](https://www.forbes.com/sites/alisondurkee/2023/09/07/trump-advisor-peter-navarro-found-guilty-of-criminal-contempt/?sh=52cb788f216b)** was found guilty of 2 counts of Contempt of Congress Sept 2023,  A sentencing hearing is scheduled for Jan. 12, 2024.

1. President Trump engaged in a massive effort to spread false and
   fraudulent information to the American public claiming the 2020
   election was stolen from him.

- Candidate Trump also claimed the 2016 **[Iowa Primary was fixed](https://www.politico.com/story/2016/02/trump-cruz-stole-iowa-tweet-deleted-218674)** when he lost that to Candidate Ted Cruz.
- When it appeared Candidate Trump might not win the **[2016 Republican Primary](https://www.nbcnews.com/think/opinion/donald-trump-claimed-primaries-were-rigged-2016-now-he-s-ncna1054391)** he claimed that was rigged.
- TV Personality Trump also claimed the **[Emmy TV awards](https://www.bloomberg.com/view/articles/2020-09-25/elections-aren-t-the-only-things-trump-thinks-are-rigged)** were fixed when his TV show didn't capture an award 3 years running.

2. President Trump planned to replace the Acting Attorney General, so that the Department of Justice would support his fake election claims.
3. President Trump pressured Vice President Pence to refuse to count
   certified electoral votes in violation of the US Constitution and
   the law.
4. President Trump pressured state election officials, and state legislators, to change election results.
5. President Trump’s legal team and other Trump associates instructed
   Republicans in multiple states to create false electoral slates and
   transmit those slates to Congress and the National Archives.
6. President Trump summoned and assembled a violent mob in Washington
   and directed them to march on the US Capitol.
7. As the violence was underway, President Trump ignored multiple pleas for assistance and failed to take immediate action to stop the violence and instruct his supporters to leave the Capitol.